# Shoulder blade vs Scapula

Tags: word-choice

Which term is common to describe the bones on our backs in daily life?

For example

Does it sound natural to say "My scapula hurts" ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Only if you're talking to a physician.

Generally, if you're in pain, one will only mention the general area of pain...

> My head hurts.
>   My back hurts.
>   My shoulder hurts.

Honestly, and I'm being realistic here, but I'd bet you that a good portion of the US population wouldn't know what a "scapula" was if you said "My scapula hurts".

Plus, it's not likely correct... it's more likely that the muscles around your scapula are causing the pain rather than the bone itself.

Comment: I can confirm that I did not know what a scapula was. In fact I misread it first as "spatula".

Comment: English terms like *shoulderblade*, *kneecap*, and *collarbone* are mostly more common than Latin or Latinate ones like *scapula*, *patella* and *clavicle*.

Answer (score 4):

The common term for the scapula is *shoulder blade*. "My scapula hurts" does not sound natural to me, as a native speaker, because  I consider scapula a scientific term.